# Как зафиксировать элемент в конце первой строки во flex-контейнере

Tags: html, css

Мне надо зафиксировать элемент в конце первой строки во flex-контейнере (который имеет `flex-wrap: wrap`).
См. примеры (обратите внимание на кнопку "Expand"):

[image: 1]

Я пробовал "закостылять" через 'row-reverse' + 'order: -1', но в этом случае элементы переносятся слева, а не справа.

[image: 2]

Вот этот сниппет: https://jsbin.com/divavosafu/1/edit?html,css,output

Ну и обратите внимание, что не влезающие элементы, которые переезжают на следующую строку должны занимать всю ширину. То есть нелья в отдельный контейнер:
[image: 3]

Можно ли как-то такое вообще сделать? Может без flex, но с float как-то...

Comment: А вынести элемент `expand` вне контейнера, или обернуть элементы `1`...`8` в дополнительный блок никак нельзя?

Comment: Я согласен с Инквизитором - если создать подблоки отдельно для 1-8 и Expand, то возможно получить искомое поведение

Comment: @alexoander, тогда вторая (и последующая) строки не смогут занять всю ширину. А это обязательно [См. иллюстрацию](https://i.snipboard.io/9lbAJk.jpg)

Comment: Наверно так, как вы описали на картинке, можно сделать только слоями или js. К сожалению, идей мало. p.s. добавьте плз картинку из комментария в основное тело вопроса с пояснениями.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе что-то похожее удалось сделать через float, но смущает несколько моментов:

1. Придется отказаться от flex модели
2. Кнопка Expand зафиксирована справа, а надо бы слева (к ближайшей кнопке в первом ряду)

Если кто-то подскажет как решить проблему с кнопкой, буду очень рад.

Код:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.item {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="right">
      <div class="item expand">Expand</div>
      <div class="item ">Right 1</div>
      <div class="item ">Right 2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
  </div>
```